# Jquery onchange etc. doesnt detect when input changed with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#kv-error-1').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    var text = $('#kv-error-1').text();
    var matches = text.split("-xar-");
    $('#test').text(matches[1]);
});

$('#test').bind("change keyup input",function(){
    var matchtx = $('#test').text();
    matches = matchtx.split("-xbol-");

    for (i = 1; i < matches.length; i++) {  
        bolumler = matches[i].split("-xtes-");
        new PNotify({
            title: bolumler[0],
            icon: "fa fa-"+bolumler[1]+" fa-2x",
            addclass: "bg-"+bolumler[2],
            hide: true
        });
    }
});
```

I change with this function but If I use DOM It bring so much notification but it has to do one time. some events are doesnt read the change..

Comment: Maybe put your html in your post as well. I just tried your code in JSFiddle and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand your issue, You may just add trigger for event

```
$('#test').trigger('change');
```

You get many notifications because you added 3 event listners(change keyup input)

Answer (score -1):

What about using the change event handler?

```
$( "#test" ).change(function() {
  alert( "text changed!" );
});
```